# Cloudant Query 2.0 unexpected behavior

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

I create an index using the below function:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.type === 'Property') {
    if(doc.Beds_Max) {
      try {
       index("Beds_Max", parseInt(doc.Beds_Max)); 
      }
      catch(err) {
        //ooopss
      }
    }
    if(doc.YearBuilt) {
      try {
       index("YearBuilt", parseInt(doc.YearBuilt));  
      }
      catch(err) {
        //ooopss
      }
    }
  }
}
```

using the cloudant Design Documents -> New Search Index and after the index is built I can issue queries like

```
"YearBuilt": [2010 TO Infinity]
```

But if I try to query the same index using Cloudant query I see weird behavior. If I go to Cloudant Dashboard -> Query and pass something like

```
    {"limit": 5,
    "selector": {
        "_id": {
            "$gt": null
        },
        "Beds_Max": {"$gte": 7}
    },
    fields: ["_id"]}
```

I see huge spike in data transmission, it keeps on receiving huge amounts of data even for the most unusual queries which are only supposed to return no more than 1 or 2 results and then hangs my computer so that most probably is not right. When I use `Pouchdb-find` npm module which has support for `Cloudant 2.0 Query` and issue the same selector as above I see inconsistent behavior, e.g. sometimes it returns 0 rows and sometimes it gives a `ETIMEOUTERROR`. If I change the index and exclude `parseInt` I can query using the same `Pouchdb-find` and even Cloudant Dashboard-> Query and get the results but in that case I lose the ability to use inequality operators which is a no go for me.

I'm open to work-arounds and even altogether different features to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Why are you storing Ints as strings? Wouldn't you get the desired effect by storing them as Ints directly rather than parsing them?

Comment: @rhyshort because it's an existing database and it has those things stored as strings and it's a huge database